# Many to Many en Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

les quería hacer la sgte consulta:

Resulta que tengo una unas tablas que requieren de una relación "many to many " ( ejemplo , users y roles, asumiendo primary key para ambas como 'id' ).

El tema es que tengo la duda como una  " mejor práctica " (utilizando laravel) si crear la tabla pivote role_user con clave primaria compuesta  (role_id y user_id) o bien, crear la columna 'id'  acompañado de las claves foráneas "role_id  y user_id").

Entiendo que la segunda opción me podría generar problemas con la coherencia de los datos ( al poder generar combinaciones repetidas ), pero evalúo esa opción considerando que laravel no me deja manejar muy bien las llaves compuestas.

¿Cuál sería una buena práctica para este caso y similares? .

De ante mano muchísimas gracias!.

Comment: hace mucho tiempo tuve una duda similar y al menos en mi caso al final investigue que lo correcto sería utilizar la primera opción sin necesidad de crear el campo id. El mismo es irrelevante en una tabla de relaciones. Si quieres manejar directamente la tabla pivote, puedes crearle el modelo RoleUser.

Answer (score -2):

La tabla intermedia o llamada también "pivot table" o "tabla pivote" normalmente sirve solamente para mantener la relación entre dos modelos, entonces no hay necesidad de poner un id como llave primaria auto incrementable ya que no se hace nada directamente con esa tabla, ahora que si tu tabla intermedia es parte de otra relación con alguna otra tabla ajena a las dos que comunica, si sería conveniente que lo llevara.

La documentación de Laravel no dice nada al respecto pero algo que se le acerca es lo siguiente:

> "Por defecto, sólo las llaves de los modelos estarán presentes en la tabla pivote.
>
> Si tu tabla pivote contiene atributos extra, debes de especificarlos cuando defines la relación."

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, en estos momentos estaba pensando en algo como crear un 'id'  y las dos claves foráneas dejarlas como 'unique' compuestas (más que  nada lo pensaba por el motivo de que algunas funciones como laravel me pide enviar el id para actualizar alguna tabla o encontrar algún registro.
Si estoy equivocado o si no sirve de mucho, agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Comment: @CamiloAraya Para actualizar la tabla intermedia hay funcionas en laravel, tales como `detach`, `attach`, `sync` así que no haría falta un id en esa tabla intermedia, aquí más información:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Y por último, Laravel aún no tiene soporte para llaves compuestas.